# Access and use in Codename One native Android classes

Tags: android, codenameone

I know that Codename One and Android are completely different frameworks. But the question is, How can I access in Codename One classes from native Android?

eg: I want to create a method called `onCreat()` that looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){}
```

In Android you have to import the package `import android.os.Bundle;`

How can I integrate this package (for `onCreat()`) and other packages from Android in codenamed One?

What should I set in Code Name One that I can access these classes. Is this possible?

**Edit:**

An other Example:

```
  import android.net.Uri;
  public void startWeb(View v) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
       startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

How can i convert this Android code in Codename One so that it looks like this and, if i click on the Button, works:

```
 protected void onMain_Button6Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
       startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

The point is that I want to understand how I make the Android code for Codename One functional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to access the android native functionality. However, the onCreate call is a special case since its a callback from the lifecycle of the Android application and will be invoked to launch the Codename One start/init methods and will not invoke your code.

To listen to those lifecycle calls you can use the AndroidNativeUtil class which has a lifecycle listener that allows you to access those features from the native interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

package com.mycompany.ecopay;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity;


public class NativeAccessImpl {
public void pay() {           
com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new  
Runnable() {
public void run() {
// your code goes here
CodenameOneActivity aActivity = (CodenameOneActivity)        
AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
android.content.Intent intent = new                    
android.content.Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:0779083353"));
aActivity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}
```