# How to test an Android native code snippet with Codename One?

Tags: android, codenameone

First off I am used to programming with Java that's why I am using Codename One to develop mobile applications.

However sometimes I see some code in Android "format" that I am interested on testing. I know how to set up basic native interface thanks to [Codename one tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

For example, I would like to test this [snippet about real time sound processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27544312/6351897). However it involves initializing some variable in the Android `onCreate()` method with data that is available in this method such as `am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);` with the use of `this` which has not the same reference in the Codename One Native Interface. Maybe I don't have to use the `onCreate()` method (which could [be reached from Codename One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600380/access-and-use-in-codename-one-native-android-classes)) but I am not an Android guru (nor a CN1 one either!), so I don't know.

Consequently  what changes do I have to make to test native Android code in Codename One native interface ? Maybe there is a methodology that I would be glad to hear of.

**EDIT SOLVED : Code used in the native interface implementation that works**

Here is the Codename One native interface implementation of the [original Android code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27544312/6351897). Indeed Android `onCreate()` method has not been used but the things that were initialized in it have been transfered in the `initRecordAndTrack()` method which is called when suited in the Codename One's form. It uses the same method as described below by @akash thus replacing `this` by `com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity()`.

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.content.Context;

public class KestudisNativeInterfaceImpl {

boolean isRecording = false;
AudioManager am = null;
AudioRecord record = null;
AudioTrack track = null;

public void initRecordAndTrack() {
    android.app.Activity ctx = com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();

    am = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            min);
//    if (AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable())
//    {
//        AcousticEchoCanceler echoCancler =  AcousticEchoCanceler.create(record.getAudioSessionId());
//        echoCancler.setEnabled(true);
//    }
    int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    (new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recordAndPlay();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void startRecordAndPlay() {
    record.startRecording();
    track.play();
    isRecording = true;
}

public void stopRecordAndPlay() {
    record.stop();
    track.pause();
    isRecording = false;
}

private void recordAndPlay() {
    short[] lin = new short[1024];
    int num = 0;
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    while (true) {
        if (isRecording) {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, 1024);
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Thanks a lot,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link
https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

In android `this` normally refer to context and to access context in CN1 you can replace `this` with `com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity()`

hope that helps

Comment: I'd also suggest using include source after adding the native interface and then debugging the native code in Android Studio if things don't work https://www.codenameone.com/blog/debug-a-codename-one-app-on-an-android-device.html

Comment: Thanks @akash! That's what I also found after writing the question and it works. I'll post the code I used. I 've already read the blog article you mentioned @Shai and it may become handy in the future if I need to debug. Thanks for the tip!